# What does this Javascript mean? SRC is very strange looking

Tags: javascript

Sorry for the bad heading but I couldnt explain it better.
im trying to make a trackback on a webshop that should allow me to send the order id, and the amount back to a page i control. The only way i can get anything on the confirmation page is by javascript. I looked at one of the examples that was there to begin with (another affiliate) and his Javascript looks like this:

```
<SCRIPT language="JavaScript" SRC="http://dev.domain.com/-119/=125123" type="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>
```

I have no clue of what this means, could anyone point me in the right direkction please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is where it is pulling the file from.  It's using a complete URL to get it (albeit an odd looking one).  The browser doesn't care that the file doesn't end .js, it just looks for what content is downloaded and parses it.

Comment: But the values -119 and =125123 are those valid? shouldnt it specify a "myfile.js" extension?

Comment: If the browser can use the URL and pull back the information it needs, it's valid.